# Problem with variables and if statements in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I've tried writing a simple batch file you can see below:

```
@echo off
title test file

:menu
set /p foo = Select option (1, 2, 3):
if foo == 1 goto one
if foo == 2 goto two
if foo == 3 goto three

:one
echo One!
goto menu

:two
echo Two!
goto menu

:three
echo Three!
goto menu
```

Writing any of the given options writes `"One!"` to screen and returns the user back to the `menu` label. I suspect the error is with the types of variable I am declaring, although I wouldn't know, since I'm new to Batch... Any help?

Comment: if you removed the whitespace before `=` from `set /p foo=Select..` and changed `foo == 1` with `%foo% equ 1` it will work, besides the concern that you still need to
 work around the fact that a person can still type any other character which you do not cater for at this point. `choice` has that built-in and only the characters defined can be selected

Comment: I suggest reading my answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) It explains very detailed the disadvantages of `set /P` and how to get it safe and how easy a choice menu can be coded using command `choice` as demonstrated also by the answers already written here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Set /P` for known selections, use `choice` instead.

```bat
@Echo Off
Title test file

:menu
Choice /C 123 /M "Select option"
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo three
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo two

:one
Echo One!
GoTo menu

:two
Echo Two!
GoTo menu

:three
Echo Three!
GoTo menu
```

If you wanted to continue using the wrong command then something like this would be more like it:

```bat
@Echo Off
Title test file

:menu
Set "foo="
Set /P "foo=Select option [1,2,3]?"
If Not Defined foo GoTo menu
If "%foo%"=="1" GoTo one
If "%foo%"=="2" GoTo two
If "%foo%"=="3" GoTo three
GoTo menu

:one
Echo One!
GoTo menu

:two
Echo Two!
GoTo menu

:three
Echo Three!
GoTo menu
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE!!** Do **not** mark my answer as correct as it is almost an exact duplicate of the other answer on here, it is simply an opinion on usage.

Anyway, as an addition to **@compo's** answer, which is 100% correct, I typically shorten it by not using `if errorlevel` and just `goto` directly.

```
@echo off
title test file

:menu
choice /C 123 /M "Select option"
goto label%errorlevel%

:label1
echo One!
goto menu

:label2
echo Two!
goto menu

:label3
echo three!
goto menu
```